# What is local-variable type inference is JDK 10

Tags: java, java-10

I was going through new [features](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3230507/java/java-jdk-10-what-new-features-to-expect-in-the-next-java.html) in java 10.

But I could not understand what is **local-variable type inference**?

Can someone please explain.

Comment: You couldn't do a little bit of searching?

Comment: @Kayaman To be fair, the duplicate is not exact, but if a question can be answered with "read the docs", it's not worth asking anyway.

Comment: I would also suggest,  if you actually want to go through the features in Java10, please follow its [official release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/10-relnote-issues-4108729.html) and not end up tentatively spamming here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now we can write `var x = new HashMap<String,String>();` instead of a more verbose `Map<String,String> x = new HashMap<String,String> ();` and the information about type is not duplicated. It is one step ahead of Java 7 type inference for generic instance creation , a.k.a. diamond.

Usage of `var` is possible within a method's scope only (hence the name: *local variable*) and it is allowed only in the statements where the type can be inferred (hence the suffix: *type inference*).

Parsing a `var` statement, the Java 10 compiler infers the type from the right hand side (RHS) expression. This means that the variable declared using `var` needs to be immediately assigned and even this:

```
var readMe;
readMe = "notAGoodVariableName";
```

OR this:

```
var readMe = null;
```

is NOT allowed.

Also, please note that since it makes code a little less explicit, if used in statements like `var x = getCapitalized('abc')`, it can create confusions for the code reader.

Finally, `var` is not a *keyword*, but a *reserved type name*. Not being a *keyword* ensures that all the legacy applications don't break. But being a *reserved type name* still means that there would be a single breaking point and the legacy applications will have to rename all classes/interfaces which are named exactly as *var* while upgrading to Java 10 (a very rare and anti-naming-convention case).

There are some rules to be followed to use it correctly, hence read more at:

http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286

https://developer.oracle.com/java/jdk-10-local-variable-type-inference

Comment: Suggestion - It's always good to reference official docs like [this](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286) and another one like [this](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/amber/LVTIstyle.html) instead.

Comment: Sure, I did just that. After saving, saw your comment. Thanks for the suggestion :)